# Build Error com.folioreader:folioreader:0.3.1

Tags: android

I try to implement folioreader:0.3.1 to my project. But my build.gradle file is showing following error, anyone help me to come out from this.

this is my gradle file:

[image: this is my grandle file]

Comment: Did you add `repositories {
        maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/mobisystech/maven" }
    }` inside your gradle file